# Loosing all my data on page refresh

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app, The flow is like this.
 1. Login
 2. On successful login, I receives a json object which i use through out the project.
 3. There are 4 tabs, and I have 5,6 http calls which manages my page calls.

When my page is refreshed, the json file becomes empty, all the $scope objects get reset. ANy suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want data to persist you should probably use Local Storage/WebSQl.

You can set/get the data which you want to persist as shown below

```
var foo = "example";
localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
var fooVal = localStorage.getItem("bar");
```

More details can be found here http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html